# python Whitespace in directory name affecting execution of .bat file

Tags: python

I have a beginner problem. I'm trying to use the Windows run app to execute a .bat file, which contains a callout to run my .py file.

The problem is the .bat file and my .py file are located in a folder with spaces in the name (C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Pyper Clip Project). So when I use run to execute my .bat file, it only looks for C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Pyper and then it stops. I don't have that directory named Pyper. How would you set the environmental variable PATH to look for the entire folder name and to include the spaces in the search? I don't think putting quotes in the environmental variable PATH helps.

This is what my .bat file has

@py.exe 'C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Pyper Clip Project\mclip.py %*
@pause

Answer (score 0):

I think you can escape blank spaces with quotation marks:

```
"C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Pyper Clip Project\mclip.py"
```